# TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge documentation

Tags: delphi, rest, indy, datasnap

I have been searching Embarcadero sources and Indy sources for hours now, as well as Google, but failed to find any documentation on TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge aka HTTPWebBrokerBridge (.net). What is it doing, what methods, properties and events does it expose.

Anyone who has a useful link at hand?

Thanks

Armin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no documentation for `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge`.

Comment: Em, that's a quite surprising answer.

- How can you know, except there is an official statement from someone saying whoever wrote the code will never document it (and why)

- how can anyone make code public and expect anyone using it in his own projects, when he does not provide any documentation?

- If the one who wrote the code does not expect anyone to use it, why does he make his code public?

- If the code is not intended to be used - why does Embarcadero inlcude it in their RAD studio?

Puzzled by your answer. Armin.

Comment: I am the primary developer of Indy, so I think I would know if here is official documentation for `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` (there is not). I did not write `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` itself, and if you look closely it is not actually part of the main Indy library itself. It is a standalone unit used to link WebBroker and Indy together. I don't use WebBroker myself, but I do know that Embarcadero uses `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` as they submit patches for it once in awhile.

Comment: Hi Remy,sorry that I dodn't recognize you by your name. You surely are competent to say what you did :-) My fault :-)

Comment: Wow, I'm new to Delphi and this was the first thing I tried to look up. It doesn't bode well :D

Answer (score 0):

I have found that: `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` has the same events as: `TIdHTTPServer`.